# I can no longer write to /emulated/0 without root or system access

Tags: root-access, permissions

I have a Sprint Galaxy Note 3. I've rooted with CF Auto Root, flashed TWRP, flashed Jellybomb, and then restored back to stock from a nandroid backup.

I'm not sure when it started, but it appears that I can't write to sdcard0 or Emulated/0 without root or system permissions.   For example, I can use Astro to create a new folder in extSdCard just fine, but it fails if I try to create a folder in sdcard0. It works from Total Commander or Root Explorer but I also get the "...has been granted superuser permissions" popup when it does work.

I can't download any files in Chrome (reports "No SD Card") or Dolphin (Download failed), and downloads from Ambiance also fail, I'm assuming because it's failing to write to the internal card, and Audible throws an error when it tries to create my data file in /storage/Emulated/0/Audible.

But setting the storage location for the camera to Device seems to work just fine, and I can take pictures and find them in /storage/Emulated/0/DCIM/Camera.

Below are the permissions I'm seeing in Root Explorer.  Does anything look obviously wrong?  Is sdcard0 supposed to be owned by Root while extSdCard is owned by System?  Or what else should I look for?

[image: Directory Permissions]

Comment: i have the same problem on my S4 Mini after root.
did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: this link is the best i found about this problem
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2602734